# Catchall term for HTML, Javascript and CSS

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

A web server responds to requests **[1]** with three types of files **[2]**: HTML (the page structure), Javascript (the page code) and CSS (the page styles).

Is there a single word or an expression that can describe all three types of files?

---

[1] *Web servers can serve all kinds of files, but keep to only those three*
[2] *The later two can be inside specific tags inside the HTML*

Comment: With respect to [1], Web servers can respond with a lot more than just these three file types. In fact, they can respond with any type of file they like.

Comment: @badroit yes, that is why `keep to only those three` is in the footnote.

Comment: I misunderstood then. I thought you meant that Web servers can only respond with these three file types as a general statement.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are asking is if there is a way to answer "what is the web server responding to the request with", and the first obvious thing that comes to mind is a "response", so all files could be considered different types of responses. You could say something like:

> The web server meets the request with a suitable response

Another word that I've heard being used when you're talking about "the data result of an IT process" is **payload**, I'm not sure how valid it is:

**payload**

- That part of a cargo that produces revenue
- The total weight of passengers, crew, equipment and cargo carried by an aircraft or spacecraft
- That part of a rocket, missile, propelled stinger or torpedo that is not concerned with propulsion or guidance, such as a warhead or satellite.
- (computing) The functional part of a computer virus rather than the part that spreads it
- (communication) **The actual data in a data stream**

Comment: Response and Payload are still too broad, they could convey other file types and data structures are being passed as well. I am trying to find something more specific to only those three.

Answer (score 1):

> HTML (the page structure), Javascript (the page code) and CSS (the page styles).

The purpose of these three languages is to render and provide interactive logic for web-pages on the client-side. Hence I suggest:

**client-side [web-page]? [rendering|display]? [instructions|code|logic]**

- `|` = or
- `?` = zero or one

Comment: Reading the regex, for a brief moment I thought this was Stackoverflow. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

After googling for some time, I stumbled into this definition:

> web standards model

It seems to be originated from this [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_web_standards_model_-_HTML_CSS_and_JavaScript).

The term has [~60k google hits](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22web%20standards%20model%22&oq=%22web%20standards%20model%22). The first 20 pages consistently use the term to refer to HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Google Scholar also brings articles that use that term also enveloping these three languages.

There is a caveat using that term, because "Web Standards" (notice that the word **model** was cut off) can refer to any W3C regulation, regardless of being about the three terms or not.